# last five minutes Log4j log analysis using Python

Tags: python, log4j

I'm trying to analyze my java application logs ( using log4j ) logged within last five minutes. I'm planning to use Python to analyze last five minutes logs ans if there is any warnings, have to send a mail to me.

Can any one suggest me, what is the best method of getting log lines for last five minutes?

I have to use python for this.

log format is as below,

```
2011-11-14 10:15:46 WARN : sample warning
2011-11-14 10:15:47 WARN : sample warning
2011-11-14 10:15:48 WARN : sample warning
2011-11-14 10:15:49 WARN : sample warning
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your log-file is sorted chronologically, you will have to parse it completely:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()
lookback = timedelta(minutes=5)
oldest = (now - lookback).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

lines = []

with open('logfile.log', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[:19] > oldest:
            lines.append(line)

if lines:
    message = '\n'.join(lines)
    # send message per mail...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me and resolve my problem. To make this process efficient, do you think, reading from the end of the file is a good idea?

Comment: You can play with `f.seek(...)` and find the good byte position within the file where you want to start to seek. Depends on the file size and update frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Analysing "the last 5 minutes" doesn't really make a lot of sense. If it were me I'd have something running constantly and limit the alerts it emits to every 5minutes.

(assuming you want to stick with log4j writing to a file...) While you could handle the file I/O in your python code, it's probably simpler to use 'tail' to pipe the file into your script. Obviously you'll need to plan for how you deal with rotating log files - presumably you already have some mechanism for this - it needs to be told to tell the python code to reopen its file handles after rotation.

It might be a lot simpler to send the data to your python script using a pipe - and let [python handle the rotation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyrotate/).

Whichever, [don't forget to add a SIGALRM](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) to force a check event in the absence of any log messages.

Comment: Initially I was also thinking of a program constantly running. But I have bad experiences with running shell scripts constantly for a long time. Because they will get hang after some time. With that I'm planning to run the program once in five minutes and put this in to cron. Thankyou for mentioning about SIGALARM. As I'm new to Python I haven't use SIGALARMS before. Thank you for your ideas.